# using fgets to read only part of the file

Tags: c, visual-studio, fgets

while working with visual studio 2012, I'm using two files. One is the `phonenumber.db` and the other is `user.db`. Although these have .db formats, its actually written in text, and saved as .db.
`phonenumber.db` only contains numbers. eg)

```
00123123
01231245
09102312
```

`user.db` contains date, other local information expressed as numbers, and etc.

```
20160922 1029000001245123 DAVID HENRY
20192034 1029300275718283 MARK  LO
```

So I used fgets to read phonenumber, and find if there is matching information in user.db.

my code looks like this,

```
FILE *phoneDB = fopen(/directory of phonenumber.db, "rb");
FILE *userDB = fopen (~~~);
bool numfindFlag = False;
char phonereadbuffer[PHONELEN + 2];
char userreadbuffer[INFOLEN+2];
while(!numfindFlag && fgets(phonereadbuffer, PHONELEN + 2, phoneDB) {
     while(!numfindFlag && fgets(userreadbuffer, INFOLEN + 2, userDB) {
      ----some function works here ----
    }
}
```

However, the problem is, when I check the log, `fgets()` work weirdly. **It reads same line twice in user.db**, and after it reads all the number parts, although I designated `INFOLEN` size to read only number parts, it also reads other character parts as well.

It should only read `20160922 1029000001245123` but it also shows up DAVID HENRY MARK, LO parts as well.

Why this happens? Is there something missing when I use `fgets()`?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. If you're using fgets, I'll assume you're writing C code.

Comment: How is INFOLEN defined?

Comment: "*Is there something missing ...*" from the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf.aspx): "*fgets reads characters [...] to and including the first newline character, [...] or **until the number of characters read is equal to n – 1**, **whichever comes first**.*"So again, *how* is `INFOLEN` defined, which value does evaluate to?

Comment: INFOLEN is 26. I tend to take 20160922 1029000001245123 and added 1.

Comment: First it read `20160922 1029000001245123` and then it read `DAVID HENRY` as `fgets`doesn't move to the next line by itself.

Comment: Yes, I think I missed fgets() working method. But I'm still not sure with loops working twice.

Comment: You don't show what is inside the loop. I guess you have some code for seeking to the start of `userDB`, right? A simple solution (not the best for performance) would be to open the file just before the inner-loop and close it just after the inner-loop.

Comment: Do you want to check all entries in `phonenumber.db`for a match or do you want to stop the first time you get a match?

Comment: I want to stop if the first time match appears. At first I tend to test and try match all the user.db lines for each phonenumber.db line,

Comment: BTW - both your `while` is missing a `)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two nested while loops:

```
while(!numfindFlag && fgets(phonereadbuffer, PHONELEN + 2, phoneDB) {
  while(!numfindFlag && fgets(userreadbuffer, INFOLEN + 2, userDB) {
```

This essentially means, that:

- you read one phonelen+2 record
- you read one infolen+2 record
- something happens in the loop body which you left out
- you read one infolen+2 record
- something happens in the loop body ...
- you read one infolen+2 record
- ...
- it stops when numfindFlag becomes false

You might have two errors here:

- if you do not read everything up to the endline character, the second infolen read will read a string.
- And even if you do read the strings correctly, you will never read a phonelen record again.

An easier to write implementation would just read the file line by line, and could use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/) for match checking.

Comment: Thanks for the flow check. I'm not sure what do you mean by reading the file line by line? Isn't fgets() enough for reading lines?

Comment: Okay, I see now, those are two different files, I missed that. Is infolen greater than the maximum line length in the second db file? If it is smaller than the length of the line (e.g. just the length of the two number records) it won't read the entire line, just the part of it, and the next call will read the reamining.

Comment: But the problem is, the rest of character parts after the numbers vary so the length of the line is not constant :(

Comment: That's why you usually specify a large enough buffer (e.g. 4000 characters) and repeat `fgets` until the resulted string's length is smaller than the buffer size -1 or the last character in the string is a newline.

Comment: I see. Then if I increase the userreadbuffer and INFOLEN size big enough, (over 4000), and read all the characters in one line. And if I parse some part of userreadbuffer, after that will those problems can be solved?

Comment: It will solve the problem which causes you to see strings in your output, but it won't solve the problem with the double loops and their conditions - both of your loops will exit the first time you set numfindFlag to true, so you'll only look for the first record in phonereadbuffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you expect `fgets` to start on a new line each time it is called. However, that's not how it works. So you'll have to read the rest of the line yourself.

Also you must make sure to get back to the start of the userDB file each time.

So your code could look:

```
while(!numfindFlag && fgets(phonereadbuffer, PHONELEN + 2, phoneDB)) {
    FILE *userDB = fopen ("user.db", "r");
    if (!userDB)
    {
        fclose(phoneDB);
        printf("file error...\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while(!numfindFlag && fgets(userreadbuffer, INFOLEN + 2, userDB)) {
        // ----some function works here ----

        // Read until end of line
        while (strlen(userreadbuffer) &&
               userreadbuffer[strlen(userreadbuffer) - 1] != '\n' && 
               fgets(userreadbuffer, INFOLEN + 2, userDB));
    }
    fclose(userDB);
}
```